# Generic List is changed while changing added class members

Tags: c#, list, collections

I'd like to histories Person Data modeled in a Class:

```
public class PersonModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

The Person data is modified during runtime and periodically historised:

```
public MainViewModel() {
    List<PersonModel> histItem = new List<PersonModel>();
    PersonModel item = new PersonModel();
    item.FirstName = "Vorname 1";
    histItem.Add(item);
    item.FirstName = "Vorname 2";
    histItem.Add(item);
}
```

When I change `item` (like in secound last line) `histItem` is also changed

```
histItem[0].FirstName = "Vorname 2";
```

When I Add `item` the second time to `histItem` I have got two duplicated List entities. Collection has got the same behavior.

I want store 'item' as a persistent, later not changeable snapshot.

Comment: You have to actually make a snapshot of its current state. You're adding *references* to the same object twice, and modifying the object as well, which will overwrite the previous changes. This does not work as you've already noticed. So you need a snapshot mechanism.

Comment: You have to create a new item each time: `item = new PersonModel();`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
 List<PersonModel> histItem = new List<PersonModel>();
 PersonModel item = new PersonModel();
 item.FirstName = "Vorname 1";
 histItem.Add(item);
 item = new PersonModel();
 item.FirstName = "Vorname 2";
 histItem.Add(item);
```

or

```
 histItem.Add(new PersonModel(){FirstName="value 1"});
 histItem.Add(new PersonModel() { FirstName = "value 2" });
```

Comment: A problem with this approach is that in general only a small amount of data will probably change, such that it probably not advisable to create\ a new instance each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer. I'm sorry, I didn't recognise that this question has already been asked.

There is a bigger problem while creating a new instance all times: The Data is getting lost. The ‘PersonModel’ class is huge (containing approximately 100 members and multiple other generic lists), only a small amount is printed out above. Every time a new instance is created the new instance (item) needs to be filled member-wise with the data. The ‘PersonModel’ class is subject to be changed.

Is there no other solution for this problem? Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with 'inbox me'?

Comment: send details to my mail, `text2meanytime@gmail.com`